# How to download a processed dataset on Azure machine Learning Work Space?

Tags: csv, azure, machine-learning

After importing a csv data file in to Azure machine learning workspace and processing it with algorithms, I am not able to downloaded the final processed data set as the option to download the data is greyed out.

Even if I save the data set to "My Data Sets" it saves. But on the My data set panel the download icon is again greyed out.

How can I download this data?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer after working various permutations for some time.
Azure stores data in a native format that you can visualize but cannot export. To be able to export the data use the model "Convert to CSV".
Once you have processed the data through that "Convert to CSV" model the data output will be available to Download and the greyed out Download icon will be active.

Problem solved.